# How do I integrate this MOSFET NOR logic gate with my circuit?

Tags: mosfet, digital-logic, logic-gates, brushless-dc-motor, h-bridge

I have got an H bridge circuit controlled by a bridge driver (not in the schematic here). I want to control the disabling of it cutting of the conection to ground. I need the logic of a NOR gate but I don't know how to integrate its circuits with the H bridge. A NOR gate with N channel MOSFETs is like this:

[image]

If you check where the output is you will see that is found in the "middle" of it. So, do I have to connect the ground of the h bridge circuit there or do I have to connect this gate in series with the MOSFETs from the bridge?

Option a)
[image]

Option b)
[image]

Comment: You connect the logic device to the logic inputs of the H-bridge. Not the power pins.

Comment: The gates of the h brisge MOSFETs are control from an h bridge driver that will drive the PWM. I can't do that. I need a solution similar to the one I am asking for.

Comment: What H-bridge driver?

Comment: It is not in the pictures. Its one commercial driver I used to drive the Mosfets' gates with PWMs. I know there are some of them with an enable pin, but I need another extra enabling, like I said before.

Comment: You could probably just use the N-channel FET(s) instead of implementing the entire gate.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis I have two logic inputs, that's why a single MOSFET does not work for me.

Comment: @DevelopingElectronics I understand, but you can eliminate the two P-channel FETs going to Vdd without affecting the operation of the circuit; the other side of the load is already connected to Vdd.  Option (a) is your correct connection, as (b) will never pass current (except in short bursts during switching).  You can see why the P-channels aren't needed.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so you are not designing ASICs or anything like that. Just putting made components together.

> I need the logic of a NOR gate

Uh, nobody is actually putting together those from discrete transistors in such applications! That's how a NOR gate *may* look when implemented in CMOS on a chip, and that's what the schematic applies to.

You want to buy a single NOR gate in a chip. Like 74LVC1G02, but there are many others that end with "1G02" but start with another 74 family prefix.  It's a little 5-pin chip that has exactly one gate in it. It'll work here as long as the supply voltage matches the logic voltage expected by the driver.

> Its one commercial driver I used to drive the Mosfets' gates with PWMs.

**You want to put the NOR gate on the input of the gate driver**, *not* on the mosfets themselves! The driver takes logic signals and uses them to control the gates. To disable or enable a gate, logic goes before the driver chip. Easy.

If you actually tell us what driver chip you're using, it'll then be possible to tell you how to hook that NOR gate in.

Comment: Hi. My questions is related to some design requirements. I cannot use a single chip for that, that's why I cannot use a commercial NOR gate and was trying to implement the gate with MOSFETs. Regarding the placing of the gate, it is another requirement, to be able of disabling the bridge in the bridge side and not in the driver side.